# temporary table does not exist in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i written a two Stored procedures in `Mysql`

```
1.business logic(SP1),
2.dynamic temporary table creation(SP2)

in Sp2 am creating temp table
in sp1 am inserting values.. 
 am calling SP2 in SP1..
```

if i call `SP1` from console application its working fine but..

if i calling `same stored procedure SP1` in `web application` its throwing an `Exception` like `temporary table not exist`..

```
why its happen like this ???
any suggestions ?? tell me the reason..
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The temp table is out of scope when you called it from sp1.  It only exist within sp2

Comment: but if i call same stored procedure in console application its working